# Void pointer initialization? If not, what is it?

Tags: c++, pointers, void

I'm trying to understand a segment of code used as a parameter in C++ but I can't seem to find another example of it elsewhere on the internet. Here's the segment:

```
void (*cb)(void)
```

Is this another way of initializing a void pointer? What is the benefit of doing it like this versus `void *cb`?

Comment: Thanks! @Cicada That's going to be a very useful link for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this example, cb is a pointer to a function which takes no arguments and has no return value

for example if I have

```
void printHello( ) {
    cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

then I could later have

```
void (*cb)(void);
cb = printHello;
```

I can call the function using:

```
cb();
```

which will call printHello();

The utility of this is that I can now assign different functions to cb and call them and pass them around to other functions like any other pointer variable.

Often for clarity, programmers will create a specific type for this to avoid having to write this mouthful:

```
typedef void (*tPrtToVoidFn)(void);
tPtrToVoidFn  cb;
cb = printHello;
```

For comparison, a pointer to a function that returns an int would look like:

```
int (*ptrToFunctionReturningInt)(void);
```

and a pointer to a function taking an int and returning nothing would look like:

```
void (*ptrToFunctionReturningNothing)(int);
```

Answer (score 2):

`cb` is a pointer to a *function* taking no arguments and returning no value.

It's often used to implement callback mechanisms: i.e. if it's passed to a function, then that function can *call* `cb` using `cb()`;